# SVG element is not clickable with selenium chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, svg, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click an svg element for which I am using css locator to locate the element. I tried using actions class but still the element is not clicked. Also I tried JavaScriptExecuter and still the element is not clickable. The other problem is that I don't get any error if the element is clickable or not.

The below method is the clickable method:

```
public void verifyBoxIsOpened() throws InterruptedException {
clickbuttonShippingAddress().waitForPresent();      
Actions act =  new Actions(wtd.getDriver());    act.click(clickbuttonShippingAddress()).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: If the svg element have no `fill` you may try adding `pointer-events="all"` as a presentation attribute.

Comment: @enxaneta what do you mean by pointer-events="all" I have the cssSelector as "#mainCheckoutFormAnchor > div:first-child > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:first-child > button > span"

Comment: Please read about [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). If the path you are trying to click has no fill it's not clickable. You need to add `pointer-events="all"` as a presentation attribute or as a rule in css. Alternatively you can fill the shape with `transparent`

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: actually the element is clickable when I do the debug but the same element is not clicked when I run the test normally.